# How to provide user-defined revisionable css styles?

Tags: 8, theming

I want to provide option for admin to attach CSS styles on specific urls(just like block visibility can be set).

This style is stored in config entity and is revisionable. Since config entities do not support revisions I am storing them in the entity itself under 'revisions' key which is an array keyed by uuid holding 'content' and 'timestamp' values.

User then only creates/edits the entity via UI and types the styles into textarea.

The issue I am facing is how to dynamically attach those stylesheets depending on the paths condition.

I wanted to do it via hook_css_alter but only 'file' and 'external' types are supported so 'inline' is not an option. Then I was thinking about hook_page_top but I think using libraries would be a better idea although I am not sure how to implement this in a proper Drupal8-way.

---

So far I have created a custom module that provides config entities with the css rules and also on each save it saves the current value as revision within itself under specific array. I am using hook_css_alter to load and attach the active styles. Since the styles don't have only status but also list of paths they are active on(just like blocks with wildcards) I don't think it is possible to attach them as libraries. Also they are just CSS so it should not influence caching in any way(imo).

Comment: Try out this module https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector

Comment: Check out the tags, he needs a Drupal 8 solution

Comment: I haven't dug in to D8 a whole lot but isn't this what the [`#attached`](https://www.drupal.org/node/2169605) can accomplish?